# unusual switch statement label - why isn't this a syntax error?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I've inherited a very old (+15 years old) C++ program currently running on AIX using IBM's xlc compiler.  I came across a switch statement and I don't understand how this ever worked.

Below is a minimal example that shows the situation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int i=5;

        switch( i ) {
                case 1:
                        cout << "case " << i << endl;
                        break;
                case 2:
                        cout << "case " << i << endl;
                        break;
                Otherwise:
                        cout << "case " << i << endl;
                        break;
        }
        cout << "bye\n";
}
```

I'm using GCC 7.3.1 on Amazon Linux 2.  The program compiles fine and shows this output is:

```
bye
```

If I add "-Wall", then it tells me the following:

```
minex.C: In function ‘int main()’:
minex.C:15:3: warning: label ‘Otherwise’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
   Otherwise:
   ^~~~~~~~~
```

Questions:

1. Why isn't this a syntax error?
2. Don't the case labels have to follow the form "case n:" where n is
   an integer expression or "default:" (or a constant String expression, but that doesn't seem relevant here?
3. Can someone please point me to a reference that says this is
   supposed to be allowed?

Comment: This is not `case` label, but a general label (that can be used by `goto`)

Comment: May be a label? For gotos and that stuff, same syntax. So it isnt even part of the switch

Comment: It's not a case label. It has no relationship with the switch. It's a normal label.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, but obviously, it doesn't work!  It's hard to imagine what the original programmer was trying to do.  In the boiled-down example, if `i` is not 1 or 2, the "Otherwise" case does *not* fire, and the code doesn't print enything other than "bye".

Comment: @SteveSummit The original programmer came from Haskell I guess :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick answer.  I never would have thought that a label was allowed inside another branching structure.

Comment: @James Just for fun, look up Duff's Device.

Comment: Maybe there is originally somewhere a header file with `#define Otherwise default`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A label can occur on any statement.  That the statement happens to be inside of a `switch` block doesn't matter.  This label can be jumped to from anyplace inside the current function.

A `case` label or `default` can only appear inside of a `switch`, but that doesn't prevent other labels from appearing there as well.

Section 9.1 of the [C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) describes labeled statements:

> *1* A statement can be labeled.
>
> labeled-statement:
>
> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier : statement
>
> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> **case** constant-expression :
> statement
>
> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> **default** : statement
>
> The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the label. An
> identifier label declares the identifier. The only use of an
> identifier label is as the target of a `goto`. The scope of a label is
> the function in which it appears. Labels shall not be redeclared
> within a function. A label can be used in a `goto` statement before
> its declaration. Labels have their own name space and do not interfere
> with other identifiers. [ Note: A label may have the same name as
> another declaration in the same scope or a template-parameter from an
> enclosing scope. Unqualified name lookup (6.4.1) ignores labels. — end
> note ]
>
> 2 Case labels and default labels shall occur only in switch statements

Note that there are restrictions on `case` and `default` but not other labels.